# ListView.ItemClick not fired in ListView with custom ItemContainerStyle

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In `ListView` with custom `ItemContainerStyle`, `ItemClick` is not fired even `IsItemClickEnabled` is set to `True`. My XAML code is in a `ResoureDictionary` inside custom control template and is

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding History}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HistoryItemTemplate}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource HistoryItemContainerStyle}"
          IsHitTestVisible="True" SelectionMode="None" IsSwipeEnabled="False"
          CanDragItems="False" CanReorderItems="False"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True" Width="400" Margin="50,0,0,0" >
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Margin="0" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

and `HistoryItemTemplate` is

```
<Style x:Key="HistoryItemContainerStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1" />        
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource HistoryItemButtonStyle}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />                    
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and C# code is

```
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    var historyListView = GetTemplateChild("HistoryListView") as ListView;
    if (historyListView != null)
        historyListView.ItemClick += OnHistoryItemClicked;
}
```

I also try to set button in `ListViewItem` Template's `IsHitTestVisible` property to `False`. This doesn't works. Every thing works fine if custom ItemContainersStyle is removed.

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same problem!!

Answer (score 1):

That happens because `Button` element in your template blocks `ListViewItem` from handling the pointer events. You need to replace `Button` with another element, like `Border` for example.

Comment: I need that button to respond to PointerOver & Pressed Visual States

Comment: @AdnanUmer Unfortunately, there's no way to do it using button. Therefore `ListViewItem` has `Pressed` state. Not sure about `PointerOver`, you can give it a try, although `ListBoxItem` has both definitely.